# Decoding gcc specs file line

Tags: gcc, replace, line, specs

I have a problem with the implicit LIBRARY_PATH modification of g++ between two versions (`g++ -v` gives this info). I set the LIBRARY_PATH to a single local directory where I have custom libraries. However, it turned out that only one version of the g++ (let's call it version A) correctly linked, the other (version B) linked to the system-default, which was not desired. Apparently, the order of directories was mixed up and my specification was not properly respected. It is a similar issue to [LIBRARY_PATH not used before /usr/lib anymore in gcc 4.2 and later?](http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2008-06/msg00115.html) although not with these versions.

Somehow I came along the idea to have a look at the specs files of the two different versions (got them via `g++ -dumpspecs > specs`). I then tried to see if running the version of g++ (B; that was producing the *un*expected modifications) with the specs file of the other version (A) would still yield that modification and to my relief the LIBRARY_PATH was now exactly as I expected it (matching version A)!

I further traced down the place of this weird modification to happen at the following line:

```
. !m64 !m32;.:../lib64 m64 !m32;.:../lib32 !m64 m32;
```

Besides appearing to affect the setting/modification of LIBRARY_PATH, I sadly have no clue what this line means.
Therefore I hope that some of you is able to "decipher" this line and explain what it means so that I can try to modify it according to my requirements.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That line affects how libraries are found relative to GCC's `$PREFIX/lib` directory (where `$PREFIX` is the directory GCC was installed to.)

There are three parts to it:

`$PREFIX/lib/.` is used when neither `-m32` or `-m64` is used on the command-line.

`$PREFIX/lib/.:$PREFIX/lib/../lib64` is used when `-m64` is used.

`$PREFIX/lib/.:$PREFIX/lib/../lib32` is used when `-m32` is used.

This suggests to me you are using Debian or Ubuntu, I don't think a vanilla GCC build from the FSF sources would have that in the specs. Were both your GCC versions from `.deb` packages or did you install them yourself? (The Multi Arch support in recent Debian/Ubuntu releases moves library directories and so breaks vanilla GCC, I think Debian and Ubuntu patch the GCC code for their `.deb` packages.)

Could you add the output of linking with `g++ -v` for each of your versions, to see the exact library search paths used by each version?

Also, why not just use `-L` instead of `LIBRARY_PATH`? Directories specified with `-L` always come first, before the system dirs or GCC's own dirs or the ones specified in `LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this may prove very helpful. The g++ ver. A is actually a Debian-provided system wide compiler. The other (ver. B) comes with a system called easybuild which is used to manage the installation and version handling on a multiuser system (potentially significantly different tool and version needs). I think the overall setup is very specific to this site and thus I didn't want to go into detail there. I don't want to use "-L" as this must be set (by definition) explicitly and I thought using "LIBRARY_PATH" would be a generic, transparent solution to guarantee "safe" default-linking.

Comment: The Debian-provided GCC is built with patches that alter its library search path, e.g. http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/gcccvs/branches/sid/gcc-4.6/debian/patches/gcc-multiarch.diff?revision=5904&view=markup and http://anonscm.debian.org/viewvc/gcccvs/branches/sid/gcc-4.6/debian/patches/gcc-multilib64.diff?revision=4969&view=markup